# strtok(NULL, ) segmentation fauls

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

Input to a piece of code is:

```
initfs /home/bin/usr/a.txt 1000 100
```

The code is as follows:

```
printf("Enter a command\n");
scanf("%99[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", userInput);
printf("%s\n", userInput);
command = strtok(userInput, " ");
filePath = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

In `userInput`, `"initfs /home/bin/usr/a.txt 1000 100"` is stored and
in the variable `command`, `"initfs"` is stored.
But if I print `filePath`, it is giving segmentation fault.
It should print `"/home/bin/usr/a.txt"`

What may be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure about what's in `userInput`? I'd expect it to stop after `"initfs "` since your `[0-9a-zA-Z ]` doesn't allow slashes.

Comment: Looks like `filePath` is `NULL`. Do you have a debugger? It's trivial to use one to work this out. If you don't have a debugger, why not? If you don't know how to use one, why not? If you can't insert `printf` statements to debug this, why not? In short, you need to learn some basic debugging techniques.

Comment: When I run your code on the input you describe, the value of `userInput` is "initfs", not "initfs /home/bin/usr/a.txt 1000 100". Are you quite sure that `scanf` is behaving the way you expect it to?

Comment: @qwrrty - Yes, userInput has only initfs. Can you please tell me how to tokenize this kind input into 4 variables?

Comment: Your problem is not the tokenizing code. It is the `scanf` code. Can't you see that your latest comment contradicts your own question: `userInput` does not have the value that you say it has.

Comment: If you mean to take a full line of input, `%99[^\n]` will be a lot easier than listing all the allowed characters.

Comment: Also `%[...]` is a replacement for `%s`, so you don't need the `s` at the end of your scanf format (it's trying to match a literal `s`, which it will never find because the `a-z` eats them all.) Overall, I endorse @qwrrty's suggestion to use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for parsing input from a keyboard, I find it much less of a headache than to read a full line of text with `fgets` (or `getline`, if you like) and then parse it from there. e.g.:

```
char userInput[1024];
while (fgets(userInput, 1024, stdin) != NULL) {
    handleInput(userInput);
}

...
void handleInput(char *userInput)
{
    char *command, *filePath;
    command = strtok(userInput, " ");
    filePath = strtok(NULL, " ");
    ...
}
```

Using `scanf` directly on user input is just too finicky and gets confused on very slight changes in input data too easily.